# Arrow head at end of spiral curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

Folks,

Here is my MWE. I need to draw  a spiral for trigonometry more than one revolution.
How to place an arrow head on the spiral where it meets the terminal end?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, cap=round, color = blue];
\draw [->] [thick, domain= 0  : 25.   90, variable=\t,smooth,samples=500] plot  ({\t r}:  {0.001 *\t*\t}  );
\centring
\draw[blue,very thick] (0,0)--(45:1cm) node[right]{};
\draw[blue] (1,1) node{};
\draw (45: 2cm) node{$\bullet$};
\draw [blue, thick](0,0) --(1.4142,0)node[below]{};
\draw[blue, thick](1.4142,0)--(1.4142,1.4142);
\draw( 30: 7 mm) node [  right] {$A$}; 
%nodes
\node at (0.7071, 0.7071)[ above left] {$\sqrt2$};
\node at (0.7071, 0)[ below ] {$1$};
\node at (1.4142, 0.7071)   [  right ] {$1$};
% axis 
\draw[->]  [blue, thick](0,0)--(2,0) node [right] {$x$};
\draw[->]  [blue, thick](0,0) --(0,2) node [right] {$y$};
\draw[-]  [blue, ultra thick]( 0,0) --( 1.4142,0){};
\draw[-]  [blue, ultra thick]( 0,0) --( 1.4142,1.4142 ){};
\draw( 0,0) node [below left] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You already have an arrow head. Is it not working? It does for me with `tikz` version 3. http://i.stack.imgur.com/avikY.png  In other words, I might have not understood - terminal end.

Comment: Thanks Harish. The arrow head upon zooming does not look proper.

Comment: It is because you are using ultra thick in `\draw[-]  [blue, thick]( 0,0) --( 1.4142,1.4142 ){};` Use `thick` for example.